# For a tab bar icon, does iOS recognize @2x for iPad as well?

Tags: ios

So, My question is will the @2x be recognized on iPad tab bar as well? I know iPad has different suffix, but just having @2x seems to work well.

Comment: It should, but this can also be tested easily.

Comment: You stated "just having \@2x seems to work" after asking "will the \@2x be recognized". If you already know it works, why ask the question? BTW - the iPhone has a different suffix too.

Answer (score 0):

The @2x and the ~iphone/~ipad suffixes are orthogonal — if you had a universal project targeting retina and non-retina versions of both categories of device then you'd likely have iPhone/iPad differentiated and @2x/normal differentiated assets.